# How to set bare domain CName record to point to S3 bucket without effecting MX record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have a static site hosted in a S3 bucket and a domain registered at Namecheap  (e.g  mydomain.com)
I would like people to access my site using the bare domain, (i.e without subdomain)
I added a DNS record like so..

```
Type = CName
Host = @
Value = [URL to S3 bucket]
```

This works but now emails to mailboxes on that domain (e.g hello@mydomain.com) don't work. I've read that this is because if a CNAME is used to  specify the bare canonical name for a host you are not allowed to have any other resource records (e.g MX) for that host.

How can I get around this? I don't want to resort to adding a subdomain like www.

Comment: take a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: That works only if the domain is hosted at Aws, as then you can set an A record to point to the S3 bucket.  
I can't set an A record from an external domain host as I won't know the IP address of the S3 bucket for it to point to

Comment: right, you need to use Route 53 for this, you can use it with existing domains not registered through AWS too. Or is there any reason you cant use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a valid configurarion to have a CNAME at the apex of a zone like this.  The DNS provider should not even allow you to create it.  Yes, it breaks your MX if you try it.

That's why Route 53 introduced A-record aliases.  See [the link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/) mentioned in comments for an explanation.  Alias records appear to behave like what people commonly assume a CNAME does, but they aren't CNAMEs and are not invalid at the apex.

To do this right, you need to use Route 53 as your authoritative DNS hosting provider.

One workaround is to create a bucket with `www.` at the beginning instead of the one you have now, create a www CNAME pointing to it, and then set your `@` A record to the value provided by a service like http://wwwizer.com, which redirects example.com → www.example.com.

I am not affiliated with that service but I have seen it used for this purpose.